# How to make a variable in a struct variable that is not inputted but set based on previous variables' values

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, c++17

I am making a program which inputs fractions and puts them in order. I used struct to define a fraction type. I think I am making a type that initializing 2 variables(the numerator and the denominator of the fraction) and initializing the double type variable called value to a / b in this code:

```
struct fraction {
    int a; // numerator
    int b; // denominator
    double value = a / b; // floating point value of fraction
    bool operator > (const fraction &a) {
        fraction ans;
        return ans.value > a.value;
    }
    bool operator < (const fraction &a) {
        fraction ans;
        return ans.value < a.value;
    }

};



int main() {
//---------logging-------
    fraction ratio = {1,2};
    cout << ratio.value;
//-----------------------
    // outputs 0
    // other things down here that is not included
}
```

but apparently, that is not the case because I also need to initialize value. I figured out why, but the problem is, how can I make the variable without initializing it at the creation of the fraction? Thanks!

Comment: Does `value` need to be a variable? Can it not be computed as needed?

Comment: This **does** work, but as written it uses integer division (as mentioned by Bob__).  It also can be overridden by the client, which might or might not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the variable without initializing it at the creation of the fraction?

One could just write a member function `double value()` calculating and returning the floating-point value of the fraction, but first there are some issues in the posted code that need to be addressed (and may actually solve OP's problem).

- The only in-class member variable initialization shown isn't correct.

  ```c++
  double value = a / b; // floating point value of fraction
  ```

  Beeing both `a` and `b` variables of type `int`, `a / b` is an *integer* division, yielding an `int` result that is only after assigned to a `double` variable. In OP's example, `int(1)/int(2) == int(0)`.

  To produce the expected value, we need to explicitly convert at least one of the terms into a `double`:

  ```c++
  double value = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
  ```
- Both the comparison operators are wrong.

  ```c++
  bool operator > (const fraction &a) {
        fraction ans;                // This is a LOCAL, UNINITIALIZED varible.
        return ans.value > a.value;  // The result is meaningless.
  }
  ```

The following snippet shows a possible implementation where `value` is calculated and not stored (which isn't necessary a good idea).

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

class fraction
{
    int numerator_{}; 
    int denominator_{1}; 

public:
    fraction() = default;
    fraction(int num, int den)
        : numerator_{num}, denominator_{den}
    {
        if (auto divisor = std::gcd(num, den); divisor != 1)
        {
            numerator_ /= divisor;
            denominator_ /= divisor;
        }
    }

    bool operator > (fraction const& a) const noexcept {
        return value() > a.value();
    }

    bool operator < (fraction const& a) const noexcept {
        return value() < a.value();
    }

    auto numerator() const noexcept {
        return numerator_;
    }

    auto denominator() const noexcept {
        return denominator_;
    }

    double value() const noexcept {
        return static_cast<double>(numerator_) / denominator_;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two solutions, either you initialize a and b with 0, or you compute a/b each time you need it.

...or you could write an exception like:

```
int a;
int b;
double val;

try() { val = a/b; }
catch(...){ val = 0; }
```

I don't think that's good tho because it's always gong to catch.